# Increment a column value of an entity in an SQL table

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, orm, sqlalchemy

I've set up the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE transactions (txn_id SERIAL, stock VARCHAR NOT NULL, qty INT NOT NULL, user_id INT NOT NULL);
```

On inserting few rows, the table looks like this:

```
txn_id | stock  | qty | user_id
--------+--------+-----+---------
      1 | APPL   |   2 |       1
      2 | GOOGLE |   3 |       4
      3 | TSLA   |   1 |       2
```

Now, while adding a new insert into the table,
for example - `INSERT INTO transactions (stock, qty, user_id) VALUES ('APPL', 3, 1)`
if '*stock*' and '*user_id*' match (as in the above example), i only want the quantity to be updated in the database. Such as in this case, the row 1 entity should have its 'qty' column value incremented by +3.

Is there a solution to this without using any ORM like SQLalchemy etc. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `on conflict`.  First set up a unique constraint on the `stock`/`user_id` columns:

```
alter table transactions add constraint unq_transactions_stock_user_id unique (stock, user_id);
```

Then use this with an [`on conflict`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html) statement:

```
insert into transactions (stock, qty, user_id) 
    values ('APPL', 3, 1)
    on conflict on constraint unq_transactions_stock_user_id do update
        set qty = coalesce(transactions.qty, 0) + excluded.qty;
```